# Are there any ordered fields containing $\mathbb{Q}$ as a non-dense subfield?

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a totally ordered field for which $\mathbb{Q}$ is not dense? The answer is yes, but I can't understand why. Can you provide an example?

Comment: There are many fields where the rationals are not even present. There are more objects in set theory than the numbers we grew up with

Comment: The field of [rational functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484689/ordering-the-field-of-real-rational-functions) over $\mathbb R$, for example.

Comment: $\Bbb{R}(x)$ is an ordered field with $f\ge 0$ iff the rational function $ \Bbb{R\to R}\cup \infty$ is $\ge 0$ on $(0,\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon >0$ (or for $x$ large enough, which gives a different order).

Comment: @FShrike  True, but not totally ordered fields.  Those all have characteristic $0$.

Comment: Any [hyperreal field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number)

Comment: @jjagmath I can't understand why hyperreal field?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that by a 'totally ordered field', you mean an [*ordered field*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field#Definitions) i.e. a field $K$ equipped with a total order $\leq$ that is compatible with the field operations, by which I mean that $x\leq y\implies x+z\leq y+z$ and $x,y\geq 0\implies xy\geq 0$.

If we drop these compatibility assumptions, then it might be possible to put a (completely unnatural) total order on $\mathbb{C}$ making it a 'totally ordered field' containing $\mathbb{Q}$ as a proper dense subfield. But of course that would be a bit silly, because such an ordering would not respect the algebraic structure of $\mathbb{C}$ (we would need $i^2\geq 0$ for that to work).

Some important points to make about ordered fields: It is clear that $x^2\geq 0$ for all $x\in K$. If $K$ were to have positive [characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)#Case_of_fields), then $1+\cdots+1=1^2+\cdots+1^2=0$, yet $1^2>0$, so LHS must be positive. This shows that $K$ must have characteristic zero. $\mathbb{Q}$ then sits inside $K$ in a natural way: we identify each $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $q\cdot 1_K$. The image of this identification is the smallest subfield of $K$, called its *prime subfield*. It can be obtained by starting with $\{0_K,1_K\}$ and extending using the field operations.

For your question to make complete sense, there needs to be a topology on the ordered field $K$. Thankfully, there is a natural choice: the [order topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology). We can define open intervals same as with $\mathbb{R}$. The order topology is then defined to be the smallest topology containing the open intervals. With a natural topology on $K$, it then makes sense to talk about the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ within $K$, and whether or not it is equal to the whole of $K$.

One example of an ordered field containing $\mathbb{Q}$ as a non-dense subfield would be the field of [*Hahn series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_series) with real coefficients. $\mathbb{Q}$ is then just the subfield of constant Hahn series with rational coefficients. The ordering is given by declaring a Hahn series to be strictly positive iff its leading coefficient is strictly positive. I suspect that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not dense in the field of [formal Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Formal_Laurent_series) over $\mathbb{Q}$ and many other non-Archimedean extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ also.

Comment: But the reals are the only *complete* ordered field. Does that mean that the Dedekind completion of Hahn series is not a  field?

Comment: @JonasFrey Correct. This may be of interest https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2010740/dedekind-completion-of-ordered-fields  Also there is a fairly simple argument given here for why any non-Archimedean field is not order complete: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362991/who-first-characterized-the-real-numbers-as-the-unique-complete-ordered-field

Comment: @JonasFrey the field of the Hahn series is complete as a metric space when you consider the metric induced by the natural valuation on the field (such metric topology coincides with the order topology). The field of the Hahn series is not Dedekind complete. As you suspect, its Dedekind completion is not a field.